# What to paint in the paintEvent implementation?

Tags: qt

The Qt's documentation says:

Many widgets can simply repaint their entire surface when asked to, but some slow widgets need to optimize by painting only the requested region: QPaintEvent::region(). This speed optimization does not change the result, as painting is clipped to that region during event processing. QListView and QTableView do this, for example.

Do this mean that when I write a QWidget's paintEvent function, there's no need to manually write codes about which part of the widget should be painted and it is all handled automatically by qt itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I write a QWidget's paintEvent function, there's no need to manually write codes about which part of the widget should be painted [?]

That's correct. The painter passed to you is already clipped to your widget's rectangle, so you can't paint outside of your widget. If your painting is cheap, then you can certainly repaint the entire widget at once, and ignore the repaint rectangle or region passed in the paint event.

You should also not blindly assume that painting only a part of the widget will be somehow inherently faster. You must measure this!

> Could you explain more about the paintevent's propagation direction, usually qt's events are propagated as child->parent, but is the paintevent different?

All widgets that need to be painted are painted. The event is not propagated, it is delivered directly to the relevant widgets, under the direction of the widget compositor.

> [...] when a Child widget's paintEvent is called, it also gets its Parent widget's paintEvent called. Why is this?

Two separate widgets happen to be painted. Just because they happen to be a parent and a child doesn't mean much. Each widget cares about its paint event in isolation. The widget compositor (backing store) has the big picture. If the parent is painted for seemingly no reason just prior to the child being painted, then likely the child isn't opaque and the parent is painted so that the child can be composited on top of it. Set `Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent` if your `paintEvent` does opaque painting and no part of the parent is visible through what's painted.